# CoffeeScript: one liner to map object into another

Tags: coffeescript

I have data in the following format:

```
data = {
  car1: {
    starting_position: 1,
    ...  
  },
  car5: {
    starting_position: 2,
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to create an object where `starting_position` becomes the key and the key in the original `data` becomes the value. I can do it like this:

```
byStartingPosition = {}
for k, properties of data
  byStartingPosition[properties.starting_position] = k
```

But I can't imagine there is no one liner to do the same...

Comment: `Object.keys(data).map(function(item) {  return {    starting_position: item  }});`

Comment: @Rayon close but you want reduce here `Object.keys(data).reduce(((obj, k) -> startpos = data[k].starting_position; obj[startpos] = data[k]; obj), {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lodash 4.1.0 or later you could do it with this function https://lodash.com/docs#invertBy

```
_.invertBy data, (v) -> v.starting_position
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7kf9wn71/2/

Comment: I know this doesn't answer my specific question (with CoffeeScript) but I'm using `lodash` and this is by far better looking solution than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce it semantically but you can make it more concise

```
byStartingPosition = {}
byStartingPosition[v.starting_position] = k for k,v of data
```

Answer (score 0):

Rayon's comment was aaalmost there. You want to use `reduce`:

```
byStartPos = Object.keys(data).reduce(((obj, k) -> start = data[k].starting_position; obj[start] = k; obj), {})
```

Although that's obnoxiously long, not very idiomatic coffeescript, and frankly less readable than your original, it is a one-liner.